# Get specific text content from an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, methods, selector, children

I need to pull out some of the text from an element on my page, using jQuery, and I can't figure out how to get the piece I need.

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="song">
    Soulstar
    <div>by <span class="artist">Musiq Soulchild</span></div>
</a>
```

I want to pull out the contents of `.artist` (in this case, `Musiq Soulchild`). First, I tried this:

```
var this_artist = $(this).children().text();
alert(this_artist);
```

That gives me `by Musiq Soulchild` (since `this` is the `<a>` element). So then I assumed that all I had to do was specify a selector inside the `.children()` method to narrow it down to the `.artist` class, like this:

```
var this_artist = $(this).children(".artist").text();
alert(this_artist);
```

But that gives me...nothing. I've also tried `$(this).children("span").text();` and, likewise, also get back nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you are using `this`, we need to know the context that the code is executing under. For example, is it inside an event handler?

Comment: `this` is the `<a>` element that I'm clicking on, because this is inside of a function attached to all anchors within a particular `<div>`: `$("#results a").live("click", function(event){...});`

Comment: with OUT context `$('.song.artist').text();

Comment: FYI, `.live(` is depricated in favor of `.on(` in version 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.children() only traverses the immediate children - given your markup .artist is not an immediate child. Use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead:

```
var this_artist = $(this).find('.artist').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect since `.artist` is not a direct child of the `a` element. Instead you need to use `$(this).find()`:

```
var this_artist = $(this).find(".artist").text();
alert(this_artist)
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kk9cJ/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.find` instead of `.children`. `.children` searches the immediate children, while `.find` searches descendants.

Answer (score 0):

either

```
$(this).find("span.artist")
```

or

```
$("span.artist", this)
```

should do it... the span is a child of div, not anchor.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an object of your link, this code returns span text:

```
var this_artist = $(this).find('span').text();
alert(this_artist);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$("#results").on("click","a", function(event){
var myartist = $(this).find('.artist').text();
});
```